# Angular 2 HTTP request parameters

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm encountering a slight problem here.

I am able to make an HTTP GET request.
When I pass search parameters, I notice a ? in the URL. Problem is, the API i'm using doesn't support/require that.

Is there a way to remove the question mark ?

Somewhere in my service.ts I have:

```
 getData(username:string, password:string):Observable<any> {
    //Parameter object
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('name',username);
    params.set('password',password);
    return this._http.get("http://192.168.20.17:8080/webshop/api/user/",{search:params})
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: By definition, search parameters go after `?`. What URL does the backend expect?

Comment: @JBNizet the back-end expects something like 'name/{name-value}'.

Comment: Then don't use search parameters. Use `http://192.168.20.17:8080/webshop/api/user/name/${username}` in backticks.

Comment: Note that you might have to urlencode the name if it contains characters that... need to be encoded in a URL.